# Does Promise.resolve wait for the passed promise to fulfill?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

If I was to have an active promise and I wanted to start a new promise but wait until that one was fulfilled would

```
var newPromise = Promise.resolve(stillActivePromise);
```

mean any chains on `newPromise` onwards would wait until `stillActivePromise` had fulfilled?

(lets pretend `someActivePromise` has a `setTimeout(..., 10000);` or something so you may want to start chaining new stuff but waiting for existing stuff to fully fullfil, be it a rejection or a resolution)

Comment: yes it does, and will also fulfill to rejected state if `stillActivePromise` rejects

Comment: yeah thats what I had hoped, can you put this as an answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Promise.resolve` is given a "pending" promise as it's argument, it will "wait" for that promise to resolve (fulfill or reject) and will take on the state and value of the passed in promise